# Can I set the datasource for a column in grid, only for one specific row?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid, xtraeditors

Hi 
I have the following requirement:
A grid control in devexpress for winform.
Column 1 for this grid is a repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit, how could I get the current row and then reset the datasource for the repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit just for this row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such tasks are usually implemented using the GridView's [ShownEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShownEditortopic) event.  You should determine the currently focused column and its FieldName (GridView.FocusedColumn.FieldName) and then change the editor's DataSource property based on the value saved in another cell of this record.  I.e.

```
private void gridView1_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            GridView gridView = sender as GridView;
            if(gridView.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "YourField") {
                CheckedComboBoxEdit edit = gridView.ActiveEditor as CheckedComboBoxEdit;
                object value = gridView.GetRowCellValue(gridView.FocusedRowHandle, "AnotherColumn");
                // filter the datasource and set the editor's DataSource:
                edit.Properties.DataSource = FilteredDataSource;// your value
            }
        }
```

Also, please take a look at the [How to filter a second LookUp column based on a first LookUp column's value](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A237.aspx) article where a similar task is resolved.

Comment: Hi, then the datasource change only happens when I want to show my field's editor. When I change the value of "AnotherColumn", how could I clean the current values in my field?

Comment: This can be done using the following code: gridView.SetRowCellValue(gridView.FocusedRowHandle, gridView.Columns["YourField"], null);

Comment: I have one question here: actually I have tried to use repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.Items.Clear(); And I find that I can also clear my field by this way: CheckedComboBoxEdit edit = gridView.ActiveEditor as CheckedComboBoxEdit;      edit.Properties.Items.Clear(); Is there any explanation about the usage when these two methods should be used and when the method you provide should be used?

Comment: The RepositoryItem is an object common for all cells in a column.  So, if you need to change items collection in the currently open inplace editor only, you should use my code and clear the editor's Properties.Items collection.  If you want to apply this change to all column cells, clear the RepositoryItems's collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `FocusedRowChanged` event, then set the DataSource based on the view's `GetFocusedRow()`.

You may need to have a separate editor with a complete datasource to show values in non-focused columns, and handle `CustomRowCellEditForEditing` to use the subset in edit mode.

Comment: Hi, if I have another column2 which is a repositoryItemComboBox, is it possible to populate different items in the repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit according to the value selected in repositoryItemComboBox?

Comment: @sps: Yes; do exactly what I just said.  (either cast `GetFocusedRow()` or call `GetFocusedRowCellValue()`)

Comment: Hi Is there any example or similar stuffs I could refer to? I am not familiar with this GetCustomCellEditForEditing

Comment: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEditForEditingtopic